# Delete numbers after specific two char in same string

Tags: python

Is it possible to remove the number after the fourth dot and the dot itself.

```
10.30.23.135.17500 > 255.255.255.255.17500
10.30.23.135.17500 > 10.30.31.255.17500
10.30.12.151.137 > 10.30.15.255.137
```

To get result with

```
10.30.23.135 > 255.255.255.255
10.30.23.135 > 10.30.31.255
10.30.12.151 > 10.30.15.255
```

Comment: is your input a multi line string?

Comment: @user_na yes a file with lines full of these strings

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can use a regular expression, or you can use `split` and `join`.

Comment: The numbers you're removing are after the fourth dot, not fifth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution you can try out using `regex`,

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/6rGngi/1)

```
import re

sub_ = re.compile(r"\.\d+(\s+|$)")

for i in text.splitlines():
    print(sub_.sub(" ", i))
```

---

```
10.30.23.135 > 255.255.255.255 
10.30.23.135 > 10.30.31.255 
10.30.12.151 > 10.30.15.255
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "10.30.23.135.17500 > 255.255.255.255.17500"
ele = s.split(">") # to split the string and create list like that : ['10.30.23.135.17500 ', ' 255.255.255.255.17500'] 
modified_ele = ".".join(ele[0].split(".")[:-1])  #here again split element of list which you want to modify, so split by "." (Dot) and join it till second last element.
print (modified_ele)
```